# Transform xml using xslt to csv file

Tags: java, xml, templates, xslt, xalan

I'm having an issue with xsl:templates and xsl:call-template tags. Perhaps it's a lack of understand , but here's what I'm trying to do...

If I have a template that's matching on "/*", and I need to call other templates from within the enclosing template that require other document contexts, what is the most efficient method of doing this?

```
<xsl:template match="/*">

<xsl:call-template name="header">
  <xsl:with-param name="headerContext" select="./[1]"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:call-template name="body">
  <xsl:with-param name="bodyContext" select="*/*/[1]"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template>
```

I'm using xsl:with-param when calling the header and body templates so that I can override the match="/*" from the enclosing template, but when I do this the output gets messed up. If I comment out the call to the "header" template, the body template works properly, and vicee versa, but calling both from the main template, as you see in the above example, makes them behave strangely. The header and body templates require a selection to different parts of the document, that's why I chose to use w0th-param, but I don't think it's even working.

Should I be using apply-templates instead?

Comment: "makes them behave strangely" in what way? Also note that your select expressions are missing a node test on their final location step.

Comment: Can't diagnose the problem from this information; but yes, you would be better off using apply-templates for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

XSL was designed to be event-based.  So, typically, you'll want to use template matching more than explicitly specifying which descendants to process.

```
<!-- Identity Template will copy every node to the output. -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- You listed ./[1] as your xpath, but you might want to add more information 
   to make it more specific.  i.e. element names, not just * and position. -->
<xsl:template match="/*/header">
   <someOutputHeader><xsl:apply-templates /></someOutputHeader>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/something/*/body">
   <newBody><xsl:apply-templates /></newBody>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, it's good practice to specify a nodeTest before a predicate. So, for example, instead of writing "./[1]" you could specify * after the slash. "./*[1]"  You also don't need to use "./" either.  It's implied by xpath.  So really, it's "*[1]"